# PHP __dir__, reference file up two levels. Is there a more elegant solution?

Tags: php

I am trying to reference the `test.php` file, which is `two` directories up from the script that is executing.

I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution

```
echo realpath(__DIR__ . '/../..') . '/test.php';
```

Using `PHP 5.5.9`

Comment: `dirname(dirname(__DIR__))`, not sure if it's "more elegant" though

Comment: imo, That is the correct way to do it. It will always work. You could have it as one string. i.e. `realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../test.php');` You don't need to use `realpath`. **It is a perfectly good filename according to the operating system** PHP just calls O/S functions. I use windows and this works. I move to linux... and this works unchanged. :) Err.. yes, windows allows '/' in filepaths. The reason it works is that it is considered an `absolute path` by the O/S. Therefore it **does NOT use the 'current working directory** to work out the path.